# NodeJS digitally sign PDF with sign image

Tags: node.js, pdf, annotations, signature, digital

I have a requirement to digitally sign pdf document and show it on the document whether signature is validated or not on my NodeJS server. I am converting my documents to PDF from DOCX and then trying to sign it. I could sign it using node-signpdf but the signature is invisible. I want to see signature validation on the document itself. Please help.

Comment: *"I want to see signature validation on the document itself."* - You are aware that that might be at odds with the PDF specification which requires that *a PDF processor shall not incorporate the validation
status of a signature (e.g. a checkmark for passed or an X for failed) into the appearance of the
signature field.* (ISO 32000-2 section 12.7.5.5 *Signature fields*).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.